# Cassandra collections serializer throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a method that is inserting into a table an Id, a set of UDT, and a date.

```
public class MessageQueueNext
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<UDTMessage> Messages { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Updated { get; set; }
}

private static Lazy<PreparedStatement> InsertStatement = new 
    Lazy<PreparedStatement>(
        () => {
            return CassandraDB.Instance.Session.Prepare
            (
                @"INSERT INTO SomeTable
                (id, messages, updated)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
            );
        });

public async Task InsertAsync(SomeObj obj)
{
    var statement = BindValues(
        InsertStatement.Value,
        new dynamic[] {
            obj.Id, obj.Messages, obj.Updated
        }
    );

    await CassandraDB.Instance.Session.ExecuteAsync(statement);
}

private BoundStatement BindValues(PreparedStatement ps, dynamic[] values)
{
    var statement = ps.Bind
    (
        values[0] ?? Unset.Value, values[1] ?? new List<UDTMessage>(), values[2] ?? Unset.Value
    );

    return statement;
}
```

At some point this method throws an exception.

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
> at Cassandra.Serialization.CollectionSerializer.Serialize(UInt16
> protocolVersion, IEnumerable value)
> at Cassandra.Serialization.GenericSerializer.Serialize(ProtocolVersion
> version, Object value)
> at Cassandra.QueryProtocolOptions.Write(FrameWriter wb, Boolean isPrepared)
> at Cassandra.Requests.BaseRequest.WriteFrame(Int16 streamId, MemoryStream stream, ISerializer connectionSerializer)
> at Cassandra.OperationState.WriteFrame(Int16 streamId, MemoryStream memoryStream, ISerializer serializer, Int64 timestamp)
> at Cassandra.Connections.Connection.RunWriteQueueAction()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Can anyone help me with what could possibly cause that? As I'm understanding the obj.Messages is changed somewhere down the road? Or like it's possible that it's changed in a function that calls InsertAsync(...), but right after calling InsertAsync(...) it changes the obj.Messages value?

Method that is calling InsertAsync(...)

```
public async Task PersistMessageQueue(UDTMessage msg)
{
    var DAO = new DAO();
    var list = await _cache.GetMessages(msg.Id);
    if (list == null)
    {
        list = new List<UDTMessage>();
    }
    list.Add(msg);
    var someObj = new SomeObj();
    someObj.ToId = msg.Id;
    someObj.Messages = list;
    someObj.Updated = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    await DAO.InsertAsync(messageQueueNext);
    _cache.AddElement(msg);
}
```

Comment: We need a larger code sample to understand the issue. What is the BindValues() method doing?

Comment: Also what are the types of the arguments that you are providing to the statement? It looks like you are passing the obj.Messages collection to the driver but your application is modifying it afterwards.

Comment: @JoãoReis Updated code. Id - String, Messages - List<CustomClass>, Updated - DateTimeOffset

Comment: Can you check in your application if obj.Messages is being modified somewhere else? Is obj.Messages a List<>? It really looks like while the driver is iterating through obj.Messages, something else is modifying it.

Comment: @JoãoReis I mean if Persist method is called by different async tasks, it's possible that some task is changing (adding to list) before other task is done iterating? That's causing the exception? So what'd be your advice to avoid such things, but keep the consistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the parent method (from your comment):

```cs
public async Task PersistMessageQueue(UDTMessage msg) {    
    var DAO = new DAO();     
    var list = await _cache.GetMessages(msg.Id);   
    if (list == null)
    {   
        list = new List<UDTMessage>();  
    }  
    list.Add(msg);   
    var someObj = new SomeObj();  
    someObj.ToId = msg.Id;  
    someObj.Messages = list;    
    someObj.Updated = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;  
    await DAO.InsertAsync(messageQueueNext); 
    _cache.AddElement(msg); 
}
```

It looks like you are storing the `List` object in a cache, passing it to the driver but each call to `PersistMessageQueue()` will modify this `List` object so you might run into the issue where the driver is iterating through the `List` object while another call to `PersistMessageQueue()` is modifying that same `List` object.

The solution is to clone the `List` object before calling `Session.ExecuteAsync()` if this is what is causing the issue.